# How to apply rotation to multiple bullets in Godot?

Tags: rotation, godot, gdscript

I have a player scene that shoot bullets every 2 seconds. I want to apply rotation to each bullet as in the image.

[image]

Here is the code in Player. I used some from a tutorial by KidsCanCode on Youtube:

```
var shoot_direction = Vector2.UP
var bullet_num = 3
func shoot(pbullet_num):
    var main = get_tree().current_scene
    
    var dir = shoot_direction.rotated(shoot_position.global_rotation)
    var spread = 0.2
    
    if pbullet_num > 1:
        for i in range(pbullet_num):
            var bullet = bullet_scene.instance()
            var a = -spread + i * (2 * spread)/ (pbullet_num-1)
            bullet.initialize(shoot_position.global_position, 
                shoot_speed, dir.rotated(a))
            main.add_child(bullet)
    else:
        var bullet = bullet_scene.instance()
        bullet.initialize(shoot_position.global_position, 
            shoot_speed, dir)
        main.add_child(bullet)
```

Here is the Bullet scene:

```
var speed = 0
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var direction = Vector2.UP

func initialize (start_position, pspeed, pdirection):
    position = start_position
    speed = pspeed
    velocity = pdirection * speed


func _process(delta):
    position += velocity * delta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `rotation` of any `Node2D` to rotate it. This is the angle in radians. The best place to set the it is in the `initialize` function of the Bullet scene, where you're also setting the other attributes:

```
    rotation = pdirection.angle() + PI / 2
```

The [`angle()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-angle) method of `Vector2` computes the angle in radians clockwise from the X axis (pointing right) to the given vector. Since your sprites are pointing "up" when they are not rotated, instead of right, we need to add a quarter turn, which is `PI / 2` in radians.